# gcc and w32api not found

Tags: gcc, cygwin, ns2

can anybody help me why these packages showed unavailable even they are installed?

I am trying to install NS2.3.5 on windows 10 64bit using cygwin.
as known, the install script of ns will check for required package in cygwin which are installed:

```
packages_base="gcc gcc-g++ gawk tar gzip make patch perl w32api"
packages_xorg="xorg-server xinit libX11-devel libXmu-devel"
```

you may notice that I modified the script to check for `gcc` instead of `gcc4` and `gcc-g++` instead of `gcc4-g++`, since the `gcc4` is obsolete.

I also run the command `gcc -dumpversion` and I got the version 4.9.3

the basic command to check the package is:

```
cygcheck -c gcc
```

and the expected output is:

```
Package     version     Status
gcc-g++     4.9.3-1     OK
```

however, the script that checks the packages failed to find `gcc` and `w32api` even they are installed. all other packages including `gcc-g++` were checked successfully and get the exact version.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, 
Tried at my end ( as I already have a cygwin package installed ).
To me, this is more of an issue of "cygcheck" utility than anything else.

At my end too "cygcheck" failed to report details in proper for "gcc", with command "cygcheck -c gcc | grep gcc"

I am suggesting a trick here to over come this, but its just a trick.

In script "install" from "ns-2.35", find a function "test_packages" and change it something like below

```
   test_packages() {
     for i in $@; do
            echo -n "Checking for ${i}... ";
            cygcheck -c ${i} | grep ${i} >/dev/null 2>&1;^M
            if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
                    echo "ok";
            else^M
                    cygcheck -l | grep ${i} >/dev/null 2>&1;
                    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
                         echo "ok";
                    else^M
                         echo "NO!";^M
                         echo "";
                         echo "Package ${i} is not present on your system.";
                         echo "";
                         echo "Please install it using Cygwin's setup.exe";
                         echo "before trying to install the ns-2 distribution.";
                    fi;
                    test_proceed;
            fi;
    done;
    }
```

Basically rechecking again with "cygcheck -l" after first fail.

This passed the test but, I did not go further with installation.

Also there is a link which explains the installation os ns-2.35 on windows

which could be useful too.

http://www.slideshare.net/TBear76/ns235-installation-3395974

Answer (score 0):

---

Please try out the 'Nov 2014 update', ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view?usp=sharing

Can use all gcc/g++ versions 4.4.x .. 5.2.0

---

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)

Comment: Please note that I try it with same problem. however I removed the check on gcc and w32api and proceed. it went through installation but I got error:
`Makefile:569: recipe for target 'tclsh.exe' failed`


`make: *** [tclsh.exe] Error 1`


`tcl8.5.10 make failed! Exiting .`

Comment: the above error is cause by the command `make` inside the `tcl8.5.10/unix` directory